# Cant use openssh on windows with key authentication

Tags: windows-10, android, openssh, private-key

I can't use my private key (i disabled password auth entirely) because Of "bad permissions"

```
C:\Users\Patron>ssh -i C:\Users\Patron\id_rsa -p 993 root@my.ip.goes.here
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'C:\\Users\\Patron\\id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "C:\\Users\\Patron\\id_rsa": bad permissions
```

The key is copied from my Android Oreo device, where termius (app) accepts the same key. The android device is unrooted, so Im not sure if I can change permissions. I tried in Termux with Fakeroot using

```
chmod 600 /storage/emulated/0/id_rsa
```

And then copied to Windows, but then I got that error. Please note that I'm not an admin

**SOLVED** I didn't realize that when I disabled inheritance, I deleted all permission instead of convert to explicit. I also didn't specifically deny others permission, I just allow me. Still cannot convert to ppk though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the Windows side (not on Android)

Change permissions on `C:\Users\Patron\id_rsa` *from within Windows*. It seems your file permissions are not being duplicated when you copy the file contents.

For example by right-clicking on that file in Windows-explorer.

Comment: So to ssh on Windows, I have to use passwords? It's a public library pc, I can't become admin

Comment: Use something like "portable Putty" instead. That should work on a library PC if they have USB ports enabled. Otherwise use something like Connectbot on your Android tablet (or phone if the screen is big enough). All of these will connect to SSH servers that only support public-key authentication. You may have to massage your private key into a suitable format but that is doable with standard tools.